# grunt watch/sass not working correctly

Tags: linux, sass, gruntjs, watch

It is my first time trying to create a workflow with grunt I have manage to make almost all work but when I run grunt the watch task for sass does nothing just outputs that the file has changed and thats it no error code nothing

gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

// All configuration goes here
grunt.initConfig({

    //jekyll tasks

    jekyll: {
    //Builds jekyll to local development
        dist: {
            options: {
                config: '_config_dev.yml',
                dest: './_local',
            }
        },
    //Builds jekyll for deploying
        live: {
            options: {
                config: '_config.yml',
                dest: './_live',
            }
        }
    },

    //jshint task

    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
            './!Gruntfile.js',
            './assets/js/*.js',
            './assets/js/plugins/*.js',
            './!assets/js/scripts.min.js'
        ]
    },

    // Uglify
    uglify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                './assets/js/scripts.min.js': [
                './assets/js/plugins/*.js',
                './assets/js/_*.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    //imagemin task
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                optimizationLevel: 7,
                progressive: true
            },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: './img/',
            src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
            dest: './img/'
            }]
        }       
    },

    //svgmin task
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './img/',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: './img/'
            }]
        }
    },

    //Sass tasks

    sass: {
        //Compiles sass to css for local test
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/sass/',
                src: ['**/*.scss'],
                dest: 'assets/css/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },
        //Compiles sass to css for live deployment
        live: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/sass',
                src: ['**/*.scss'],
                dest: 'assets/css',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },
        //Compiles sass for browser sync
        style: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/sass',
                src: ['**/*.scss'],
                dest: 'assets/css',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },

    },

    //Watch tasks
    watch: {

        scss: {
            files: 'assets/sass/*.scss',
            task: ['clean', 'sass:dist'],
            options: {
                spaw: false,
                },
        },
        style: {
            files: 'assets/sass/*.scss',
            task: ['sass:style'],
        },
        js: {
            files: [
                    '<%= jshint.all %>'
                    ],
            tasks: ['jshint','uglify'],
            },
        jekyll: {
            files: [
                    '_layouts/*.html', 
                    '_includes/*.html', 
                    'assets/css/main.css', 
                    '*.html', 
                    '*.md', 
                    '_post/*.md'
                    ],
            tasks: ['jekyll:dist'],
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            },
            files: [
                    '_local/**'
                    ],
                },
        },  

    //Clean task
    clean: {
        dist: [
            'assets/css/main.css',
            'assets/js/scripts.min.js'
        ]   
    },

    //Server
    connect: {
        server : {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                base : './_local/',
                port: 4000
        }
    }
}



});

// Load the plugins

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svgmin');  
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jekyll');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');


// Custom tasks
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['clean', 'sass:dist', 'uglify', 'imagemin','svgmin', 'jekyll:dist', 'connect:server', 'watch']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'sass:live', 'uglify','imagemin', 'svgmin', 'jekyll:live']);
grunt.registerTask('css', ['clean', 'sass:dist', 'uglify', 'imagemin','svgmin', 'jekyll:dist', 'connect:server', 'watch:style']);

};
```

My file structure is the next:

```
gruntfile.js
assets/
      css/
      sass/
```

And this is the output of the terminal when running grunt dev task as you see nothing changes

```
┌[~/git/Nutricorp] [dev *]← →[*+?] 
└[ % ± ]>> grunt dev -v                                                                                                                                                         O_O 
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-contrib-imagemin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/package.json...OK
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...OK
+ imagemin

Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
+ connect

Registering "grunt-svgmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-svgmin/package.json...OK
Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...OK
+ svgmin

Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/package.json...OK
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
+ jshint

Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
+ uglify

Registering "grunt-jekyll" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-jekyll/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-jekyll/package.json...OK
Loading "jekyll.js" tasks...OK
+ jekyll

Registering "grunt-contrib-sass" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-sass/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-sass/package.json...OK
Loading "sass.js" tasks...OK
+ sass

Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean/package.json...OK
Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
+ clean
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ css, default, dev

Running tasks: dev

Running "dev" task

Running "clean" task

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
Verifying property clean.dist exists in config...OK
Files: assets/css/main.css -> dist
Options: force=false, no-write=false
Options: force=false, no-write=false
Cleaning assets/css/main.css...OK

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Verifying property sass.dist exists in config...OK
Files: assets/sass/_config.scss -> assets/css/_config.css
Files: assets/sass/_grids.scss -> assets/css/_grids.css
Files: assets/sass/_main-page.scss -> assets/css/_main-page.css
Files: assets/sass/_menu.scss -> assets/css/_menu.css
Files: assets/sass/main.scss -> assets/css/main.css
Options: (none)
Writing assets/css/main.css...OK
File assets/css/main.css created.

Running "uglify" task

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.dist exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> ./assets/js/scripts.min.js
Options: banner="", footer="", compress={"warnings":false}, mangle={}, beautify=false, report="min"
>> Destination ./assets/js/scripts.min.js not written because src files were empty.

Running "imagemin" task

Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Verifying property imagemin.dist exists in config...OK
Options: cache, optimizationLevel=7, progressive
Minified 0 images (saved 0 B)

Running "svgmin" task

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
Verifying property svgmin.dist exists in config...OK
Options: (none)
Total saved: 0 B

Running "jekyll:dist" (jekyll) task
Verifying property jekyll.dist exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: config="_config_dev.yml", dest="./_local"
`jekyll build --destination ./_local --config _config_dev.yml` was initiated.


Jekyll output:
Configuration file: _config_dev.yml
            Source: /home/cruznick/git/Nutricorp
       Destination: ./_local
      Generating... done.

Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Verifying property connect.server exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: protocol="http", port=4000, hostname="0.0.0.0", base="./_local/", directory=null, keepalive=false, debug=false, livereload, open=false, useAvailablePort=false, middleware=null
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:4000

Running "watch" task
Waiting...Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.scss.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.style.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.js.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.jekyll.files exists in config...OK
Live reload server started on port: 35729
Watching assets/sass/_config.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/_grids.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/_main-page.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/_menu.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/main.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/_config.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/_grids.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/_main-page.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/_menu.scss for changes.
Watching assets/sass/main.scss for changes.
Watching _layouts/main.html for changes.
Watching _includes/head.html for changes.
Watching _includes/menu.html for changes.
Watching assets/css/main.css for changes.
Watching index.html for changes.
Watching .git for changes.
Watching .sass-cache for changes.
Watching _includes for changes.
Watching _layouts for changes.
Watching _live for changes.
Watching _local for changes.
Watching _locales for changes.
Watching _plugins for changes.
Watching _posts for changes.
Watching assets for changes.
Watching img for changes.
Watching node_modules for changes.
Watching README.md for changes.
OK
>> File "assets/sass/_menu.scss" changed.

Live reloading assets/sass/_menu.scss...
Live reloading assets/sass/_menu.scss...
Completed in 0.002s at Thu Mar 27 2014 08:02:04 GMT-0600 (CST) - Waiting...
```

And I dont know why it doesnt work no error message any ideas thanks in advance
ps: also tried with grunt contrib compass and it didnt work i'm running archlinux with ruby 2.1.0p0 and sass and compass gems installed everything else works great 
ps2: my shell is zsh if that is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your watch config you have `task:` instead of `tasks:`.

The key for specifying that property is plural.